# Convert Chinese Form Data to English?

Tags: javascript, translation, google-translate

A client we've been working with intends to make a Chinese / English version of an event booking website. While we can do this with [Google's translation tool](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) I was wondering if it was possible to **convert form data** - which might be in Chinese, to English.

So a Chinese tourist may make a booking using the form, the script detects chinese characters and then translates to English so their booking can be processed here in Australia.

Is this possible? Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you could detect the use of Chinese characters (character page / range would work) and integrate an automatic translation service in your form processing script. However, I really recommend against this, because automatic translation from/to Chinese is still in its infancy stage and you likely won't even get the gist of what the Chinese visitors were writing to you. If you send the Chinese original text to Australia, people can at least use several automatic translators and dictionaries in order to figure out what might be meant.

How is this company expecting to respond to the Chinese customers? Machine translation is definitely unacceptable there, because the Chinese customers won't understand it, or if they did, they wouldn't trust a company that relies on machine translation. To have Chinese customers, definitely hire at least one Chinese-speaking staff member, who can read Chinese booking requests and respond to them appropriately. Should not be too difficult, nor too expensive, to find such an employee in Australia.